# How-to select dynamic nodes in Polymer?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am trying to set up mouse events for an element stamped out by dom-repeat. The event should trigger a style change for a different element  in the dom-repeat template, basically just a color change for an icon in a box on a box hover.

As automatic node finding is not available for dynamic nodes, the docs say I should use the $$ selector.

However, $$ only returns the first node in the local DOM that matches selector, and I want the hover effect for all boxes stamped out by the dom-repeat.

As $$ selects an element's property, that leaves me thinking I would need to set up a dynamic attribute for the icon from the dom-repeat, so that I can select every repeated icon instance in the mouse event change functions.

The  repeater gives me the index, but how would I set a dynamic property with it, instead of a dynamic value?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var nodes = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll(...)
```

If you modify the DOM you might need to use the `Polymer.dom(...)` API for the individual nodes you are modifying.

```
Polymer.dom(nodes[i])...
```

Comment: Thank you! Got it to work with these mouse events: `hoverColor: function(e) {
      var nodes = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('.icon');
      var i = e.model.index;
      Polymer.dom(nodes[i]).setAttribute('id', 'hoverIcon');
    },

    colorBack: function(e) {
      var nodes = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('.icon');
      var i = e.model.index;
      Polymer.dom(nodes[i]).removeAttribute('id');
    }`

Comment: Glad to hear! Thanks for the feedback :)